# How to set size of nested structure?

Tags: c, struct

I'd like to make a simple database without making a dynamic sized array. I thought nested structure can help me, but so far it's nothing but pain. This was my idea when I started:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXDOG 50
#define MAXCHAR 20

    struct allDog {
        int size;
        struct oneDog[MAXDOG] {
            char dogName[MAXCHAR];
            char OwnerName[MAXCHAR];
        };
    };
```

I'm pretty sure that my problem is the [MAXDOG] part after struct oneDog, can I give a static size somehow to the inner structure?

You can read the part of the exam I try to do below:

*The program asks for the Dog's & Owner's name (MAX 50) then prints out the data. You can't use dynamic arrays...*

Answer (score 4):

You're overcomplicating things - try this:

```
#define MAXDOG 50
#define MAXCHAR 20

typedef struct {        // struct which defines one dog
    char dogName[MAXCHAR];
    char ownerName[MAXCHAR];
} Dog;

typedef struct {        // struct which contains array of dogs
    int size;           // no of dogs in array currently
    Dog dogs[MAXDOGS];  // array of up to MAXDOGS dogs
} Dogs;
```

Comment: Note: You are overcomplicating things, too.  By introducing a typedef.

Comment: I personally like the typedef syntax better - it's more readable to me, despite the perceived complexity. I'm usually in favor of more readable (but often more verbose) code.

Comment: @wildplasser: this is C, not C++ - `typedef`s tend to be useful, in general, as the code evolves.

Comment: I use typedef as well only I left it out from this example code. I tried it out and it works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You sized the type not the member, syntax is:

```
struct allDog { // type
        int size;
        struct oneDog { // type
            char dogName[MAXCHAR];
            char OwnerName[MAXCHAR];
        } dogs[MAXDOG]; // member
    };
```

Take care to be consistent with caps in naming, member `OwnerName` should be written `ownerName` to be consistent with other members. Types are generally typed `AllDog` and `OneDog`, to differentiate in between members and types.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works as well. I try to be more consistent!